# Join with multiple conditions OR and AND

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I know it will be like duplicate question but i don't understand how to figure it. I've two tables with join. First i tried to do it without join with using where clause. But it takes too much. In sql-side query basically looks like this.

```
select P.username
from   product P with(nolock) 
INNER JOIN voipFree V with(nolock) ON ((P.Id= V.DiscountID  OR V.DiscountID  = P.DERIVED_FROM) AND (V.ISBUNDLE IN (2,1))) OR   (V.ISBUNDLE NOT IN (2,1) AND P.DiscountID  = V.DiscountID  )
```

As i said at first i tried with where clause like this.

```
var result = (from x in productContext
              from y in voipFreeContext
              where ((x.Id == y.DiscountId || x.DerivedFrom == y.DiscountId) && y.IsBundle == 1 && y.IsBundle == 2) ||
                     (y.IsBundle != 2 && y.IsBundle != 1 && y.DiscountId == x.DiscountId))
              select x.Username).FirstOrDefault();
```

It is doesn't work as expected. Is there a way to do it with Join or better performance with where?

Comment: `y.IsBundle == 1 && y.IsBundle == 2` should be `(y.IsBundle == 1 || y.IsBundle == 2)`. That's all.

Comment: `NOLOCK` is a usually a really bad idea, only use it if you really know what you are doing